# Recovery is not Seandroid Enforcing(Samsung A5)

Tags: rooting, usb, odin

I recently bought a Samsung A510FD(Android v5.1.1) and attempted to root it but failed and this messaged appeared on my screen: RECOVERY IS NOT ENFORCING.I was then unable to shut my phone down.By force shutting down my phone with (power off button + volume down button) would cause it to on again.I tried connecting my phone to my computer via USB but my computer wouldn't detect it as well as Odin. Please help me ASAP!

Comment: Recovery is not enforcing means that the a checksum failed, indicating you are rooted. It never breaks from that alone.

Comment: Huh?I don't get what you mean. EDIT:I am actually the asker.
Sorry! It is actually RECOVERY IS NOT SEANDROID ENFORCING. (Tried Kies too)

Comment: @XenRon It means that the system is modified I.e. by rooting. Quick question- what did you backup?

Comment: installed recovery version does not match to OS version currently is in use.

Comment: *"Recovery is not SEANDROID enforcing"* is a message from TWRP indicating selinux is in desired state. kernel must allow selinux permissive in order to grant TWRP root access (not enforced). *"Set Warranty Bit: recovery"* is a message from bootloader and indicates bootloader is unlocked + device has custom recovery. Both messages are just warnings and not the cause of your issue, nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

To my experience, the non-SEAndroid enforcement is just a warning, after installing Cyanogenmod on my S4 I had that error every boot, and it still worked.

Try flashing the stock firmware if you cannot get it to boot, perhaps your rooting method is broken.

In case you don't already know, that warning trips one of the warranty bits

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**
I rooted my S5 Neo G903W using CF-Autoroot and stuck on boot screen with the red message.. SEAndroid not enforcing...

I simply installed TWRP recovery and formatted "Daliv-Cache" & "Cache" and able to boot.